# Checking for an element in an array with jsonpath_ng fails with JsonPathParseError

Tags: python, json, jsonpath, json-path-expression, jsonpath-ng

I am trying to filter elements of my JSON data which contain specific values in an array with jsonpath_ng in Python. The data looks like

```
[
  {
    "id": "a",
    "test": [
      "a1",
      "a2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "b",
    "test": [
      "a1",
      "a3"
    ]
  }
]
```

Testing the data in PyCharm with the query `$[?(@.test contains "a2")]` or `$[?("a2" in @.test)]` works just fine and returns the expected result

```
[
  {
    "id": "a",
    "test": [
      "a1",
      "a2"
    ]
  }
]
```

Trying this with `jsonpath_ng` in Python unfortunately results in an error...

```
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

a = [{"id": "a", "test": ["a1", "a2"]}, {"id": "b", "test": ["a1", "a3"]}]

jpexpr = parse('$[?(@.test contains "a2")]')
```

results in an error `jsonpath_ng.exceptions.JsonPathParserError: Parse error at 1:11 near token contains (ID)`. Using `jpexpr = parse('$[?("a2" in @.test)]')` shows a similair behaviour `jsonpath_ng.exceptions.JsonPathParserError: Parse error at 1:9 near token in (ID)`

Neither with searching Google nor SO could I find an answer whether I'm doing something wrong of if there is a limitation in `jsonpath_ng`.

Is there just no support of this filter in `jsonpath_ng`? Does anyone have a great idea for a workaround if this was the case?

Thank you all for your assistance,
.kai

Comment: Okay, found out that the helpful array operators are not at all part of the "official" JSON Path specification. Would still be grateful for a suggested workaround.

Comment: The source for the operators I was using:
https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html#filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jpexpr = parse('$[?(@..test[?(@ == "a2")].`len` > 0)]')
```

did the job for me...

```
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

a = [{"id": "a", "test": ["a1", "a2"]}, {"id": "b", "test": ["a1", "a3"]}]

jpexpr = parse('$[?(@..test[?(@ == "a2")].`len` > 0)]')

for i in jpexpr.find(a):
    print(i.value)
```

resulted in

```
{'id': 'a', 'test': ['a1', 'a2']}
```

exactly as I wanted.